# PHP login then redirect

Tags: php, authentication

I am using the following code to log users in to a series of secure pages - I need to have each user redirected to an appropriate page once submitted, I'm wondering what steps I need to take to single out the three login levels (admin,special,user):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    function check_login($level) {

        $username_s = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']); 

        $sql = "SELECT user_level, restricted FROM login_users WHERE username = '$username_s'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $user_level = $row['user_level'];
        $restricted = $row['restricted'];

        $sql = "SELECT level_disabled FROM login_levels WHERE level_level = '$user_level'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $disabled = $row['level_disabled'];

        if($disabled != 0) { include('disabled.php'); exit();

        } elseif($restricted != 0) { include('disabled.php'); exit();

        } elseif($user_level <= $level) { // User has authority to view this page.      

        } else { include('user_level.php'); exit();

        }

    }

} else {

    function check_login($level) { exit(); }
    include('login.inc.php'); exit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the login level in a [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable and then redirect the user based on that as you'll want to keep track of that login level from page to page. To redirect them, use [header()](http://ditio.net/2008/10/04/php-redirect-header-location/) with a Location: string.

For ex:

```
if ($_SESSION['log_level'] == 'admin') {
   header("Location: admin.php");
} else if ($_SESSION['log_level'] == 'editor') {
   header("Location: editor.php");
} else if ($_SESSION['log_level'] == 'author') {
   header("Location: author.php");
}
```

Comment: I get the concept I just havent been able to write my own code for it yet

Comment: i've tried a bunch of variations for this I cant get it to work

Comment: well in one of the included documents I have a $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; which is overriding my stuff here, so I tried removing that and now nothing is happeneing

Comment: What do you mean it's overriding stuff? It's just a variable. It doesn't have anything to do with setting session variables or setting location headers.

Comment: I simply cant get this thing to redirect anywhere, that HTTP_REFERER is taking it to a certain page everytime I think

Comment: No, the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] variable just contains the page the user arrived at this page from. If you header location call isn't working, it could be a "headers already sent" problem. You have to make sure you're not emitting any html or even whitespace, including linebreaks before your opening php tag or the header call won't work. If you're unsure if this is the problem, you can also try adding ob_start(); right after your opening php tag and ob_end_flush(); at the end, before your closing tag. This will buffer your output in case this is the source of your header problem.

Comment: I dont have any spaces in these areas - It just seems as though its not even recognizing that block of code, it doesn't error or anything!

Comment: The "headers already sent" is a warning, not an error, but it means your header() call won't work. If you don't have the server configured to emit warnings you won't see them. Two more things to check - that you're not echo'ing any html from inside your php script before the header calls as well, and make sure when you save your file you save it without a BOM (byte order mark) - a lot of servers (usually apache) interpret files with a BOM as emitting and you have the same issue.

Comment: I just realised the variables arent being stored properly, its only storing the "username" but not the "user_level"

Answer (score 0):

I'd move those function calls out of the if statement and keep it somewhere else...

One approach could be declaring the different levels you like in an array:  `$levels = array('admin' => '/admin/url', 'special' => '/special/url', 'guest' => '/guest/url');` and iterate through the list or see if the key exists ...

Using switch is another approach ...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login_level'])) { 
      switch ($_SESSION['login_level']) {
          case 'admin': 
               header('Location: /admin/url');
               break;
          case 'special':
               header('Location: /special/url');
               break;
          case 'guest':
               header('Location: /guest/url');
               break;
          default:
               do_login();
               break;
       }
  } else { 
      do_login();
  }

 function do_login() {
     // do something
 }
```

Comment: in what sense?  copy paste?  i make no claims that the above is perfect code ... :)