# How do i redirect after login? php

Tags: php, html, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP login then redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436245/php-login-then-redirect)

I've just made a php login page. Upon entering their data, the information is submitted back to the same page where validation occurs.

I'm just not sure how i go to my content page after this is done.

Do i use a require statement that only runs if validation is successful?

I read a similar post on SO and the solution was:

```
public void redirect(mixed $url, boolean $terminate=true, integer $statusCode=302)
```

But im not really sure what im supposed to put where, and which of those terms i literally enter versus which terms are placeholder values that im supposed to fill with something. Also not sure if $url can be filled with a relative url like memberpage.php.

Some clarification would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
Wait...public void... isnt that java terminology?

Comment: And yes, public void is java, or C (++, #).

Answer (score 3):

On successful login, set whatever `$_SESSION` variables you need (if appropriate), then redirect using:

```
header ("Location: mypage.php");
```

Remember, you need to send this header before outputting (echoing) anything.

Comment: Thank you! And the reason for that is because it will overwrite anything i output, correct?

Comment: The reason is: once something has been outputted, headers cannot be sent.  If you have an echo before you send the header, you can buffer it using ob_start() at the top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a redirect in your header. Code would be something like this:

login_validator.php

```
validation code
if(isvalid(login)){
    header('Location: loggedin/welcome.php');
}else{
    some other handler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm getting this right, you have a user input information, and hit submit - that form then posts to itself where you have php at the top that says something like

```
<?PHP 
    if(isset($_POST[name]){ 
        //input everything 
    } 
?>
```

If this is true, you can just put a line that say something like this:

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html') ;
```

inside, at the very bottom of that previous if statement.